# object member assignment in python

Tags: python

```
class Func:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weight = 0
class Skill:
    def __init__(self, bson):
        self.f = [Func()]*5
        for i in range(0,5):
            self.f[i].weight = bson['w'+str(i+1)]
d = {"w1":20,"w2":0,"w3":0,"w4":0,"w5":0}

s = Skill(d)
print s.f[0].weight
```

The output is 0 rather than 20. I am always hard to figure out the difference of class member and object member in python.

Comment: This is not an issue with instance attributes; you created a list with 5 references to *one* instance of the `Func()` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not create the list of `Func` in this way

```
self.f = [Func()]*5
```

You should use a list comprehension or some other method

```
self.f = [Func() for _ in range(5)]
```

In the first method, you are creating a `list` of length 5, with all elements pointing to the **same instance** of a `Func`. You don't want this, you want to create a `list` of **5 different instances** of `Func`.